# Stripe Balance Transactions for connect accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Hi I'm working on a project where I have to retrieve a users stripe balance transaction history using the stripe connect api. So I have my users access_token, but I'm having trouble working out how to use that with the `Stripe::BalanceTransaction` request.

For example if I want to retrieve the balance I can do:

```
Stripe::Balance.retrieve({:stripe_account => access_token})
```

However The same thing doesn't work for BalanceTransaction

```
Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all({:stripe_account => access_token})
```

Obviously I'm missing something, but after looking through the API documentation, I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: does such api exist in the documentation? what's the error?

Comment: From what I can tell, for an account you have connect authorisation for, you should be able to retrieve all the data you could for your own account.

Comment: are you able fetch 1 `BalanceTransaction`? if yes how? and are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all({/*insert params*/},{:stripe_account => access_token})
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to include details about how this answers the question, rather than just providing a single line of code.